# Displaying number of messages sent by each category of users

Tags: python, django

This is what `message_user_id` contains:

```
message_user_id = Message.objects.all()
```

This is my context dictionary in `admin.py`:

```
'msg' : message_user_id,
```

This is my `Message` class in `models.py`:

```
class Message(models.Model):
  message_text = fields.EncryptedTextField(blank=True, null=True)
  conversation_id = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  origin_user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, default=None)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

This is `UserInfo` class:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  is_buyer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_professional = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

There are different roles for users that they can choose from while sign up. That information stays in `UserInfo` table which I'm referencing to as a foreign key in `origin_user` field in `Message` class. `origin_user` in `Message` contains the same information as `id` in `UserInfo`.

I want to display the number of messages sent by each category of users. How do I achieve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are not many types you can do a search for each type and count how many messages there are, e.g. for Buyer:

```
messages_of_buyers = Message.objects.select_related(
        'user_info'
    ).filter(
       user_info__is_buyer=True 
    ).count()
```

Comment: That solved it, Thanks mate!.